# Dynamically insert image source into modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm an amateur webdev coding a portfolio site for a friend, but I'm having trouble with making the gallery functional. My goal is to insert the thumbnail image URL into the modal without having to assign each thumbnail image with an ID or make a million modals for each image uploaded. I don't know if that's feasible—if it is, I'm stumped.

Here's the HTML code.

```html
<div class="column is-4-desktop">
  <figure class="is-128x128">
    <a href="#" class="modal-link" data-target="imgModal">
      <img id="imgId" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" alt="Test">
    </a>
    <figcaption class="buttons are-small is-centered">
      <a href="#" class="button is-link">Market</a>
      <a href="#" class="button is-link">Itch.io</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
...
<section id="imgModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <img id="modalImage" src="" />
  </div>
  <button class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close"></button>
</section>
```

And here's the Javascript.

```js
 // get all "modal" elements
 var rootEl = document.documentElement;
 var $modals = getAll('.modal');
 var $modalButtons = getAll('.modal-link');
 var $modalCloses = getAll('.modal-background, .modal-close, .modal-card-head .delete, .modal-card-foot .button');

 // check if modals exist
 if ($modalButtons.length > 0) {

   // add click event for each
   $modalButtons.forEach(function ($el) {
     $el.addEventListener('click', function () {

       // get the target from data-target
       var target = $el.dataset.target;
       var $target = document.getElementById(target);

       // toggle "is-active" class on modal and "is-clipped" on html
       rootEl.classList.add('is-clipped');
       $target.classList.add('is-active');

       // change img src in modal to that of the full img
       var imgInput = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
       var modalImg = document.getElementById('modalImage');
       modalImg.src = imgInput.src;
     });
   });
 }
 
 // make it work!
 function getAll(selector) {
   return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), 0);
 }
```

When I run the code, the image source shows up as undefined. If someone could point me to the right direction or fix up this code, that'd be great!

Comment: your issue is probably on this `var imgInput = document.getElementsByTagName('img');`.. it's getting an HTML Collection not an Element, so the "src" property is undefined

Comment: @noobHere That makes sense, thanks for the clarification. Is there any way I can utilize the HTML Collection to spit out the URL for each image, depending on what thumbnail the user clicks on, through a loop of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below i modified your code from getElementsByTagName which returns a collection to querySelector which returns the first element that matches your selector. its similiar to getElementsByTagName[0] but should make your intentions clearer down the road.
Edit: updated logic to get img based on link that is clicked.

```js
// get all "modal" elements
 var rootEl = document.documentElement;
 var $modals = getAll('.modal');
 var $modalButtons = getAll('.modal-link');
 var $modalCloses = getAll('.modal-background, .modal-close, .modal-card-head .delete, .modal-card-foot .button');

 // check if modals exist
 if ($modalButtons.length > 0) {

   // add click event for each
   $modalButtons.forEach(function ($el) {
     $el.addEventListener('click', function () {

       // get the target from data-target
       var target = $el.dataset.target;
       var $target = document.getElementById(target);

       // toggle "is-active" class on modal and "is-clipped" on html
       rootEl.classList.add('is-clipped');
       $target.classList.add('is-active');

       // change img src in modal to that of the full img
       var modalImg = document.getElementById('modalImage');
       modalImg.src = this.querySelector('img').src;
     });
   });
 }

 // check if modal closes
 if ($modalCloses.length > 0) {

   // add click event for modal closing
   $modalCloses.forEach(function ($el) {
     $el.addEventListener('click', function () {
       closeModals();
     });
   });

 }

 // add hotkey to close modals
 document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
   var e = event || window.event;
   // press escape to close modal
   if (e.keyCode === 27) {
     closeModals();
   }

 });

 // removes "is-active" from modal and "is-clipped" from html to close modal
 function closeModals() {
   rootEl.classList.remove('is-clipped');
   $modals.forEach(function ($el) {
     $el.classList.remove('is-active');
   });
 }

 // make it work!
 function getAll(selector) {
   return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), 0);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column is-4-desktop">
  <figure class="is-128x128">
    <a href="#" class="modal-link" data-target="imgModal">
      <img id="imgId" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png" alt="Test">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="modal-link" data-target="imgModal">
      <img id="imgId2" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/Img/logos/talent/logo-sotalent.png?v=fbc8317caf83" alt="Test">
    </a>
    <figcaption class="buttons are-small is-centered">
      <a href="#" class="button is-link">Market</a>
      <a href="#" class="button is-link">Itch.io</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
...
<section id="imgModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <img id="modalImage" src="" />
  </div>
  <button class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close" value="Button"></button>
</section>
```

Comment: This worked for the first image, but I checked with another image and it didn't seem to change the image URL.

I'm trying to make it possible to dynamically link specific thumbnail image URLs into the modal. If I select one thumbnail, the modal would show that thumbnail. If I select another thumbnail, then the modal would show a different thumbnail.

Comment: @Lev updated the logic to support multiple links possible for clicking.